# Password strength script failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a little script to check the password strength in an inscription form, here is a relevant part of the script:

```
    $('#password').keyup(function(){

    var password = $(this).val();
    password = $.trim(password);

    var lettre_min = /[a-z]/;
    var lettre_maj =/[A-Z]/;
    var nombre = /[0-9]/;
    var symbole = /[\`\!\"\?\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\-\+\=\{\[\}\]\:\;\@\'\~\#\|\\\<\,\>\.\/]/;

    if(password.length != 0)
    {   
        //password moin de 8 caractères
        if(password.length <8)
        {
            $('.bar').animate({width:'50px',height:'5px'},200).show();
            $('.bar').css('background-color','red');
            $('.error').text('Too short').show();
        }else

        //password faible
        if((password.match(lettre_min)) && password.length <12)
        {
            $('.bar').animate({width:'75px',height:'5px'},200).show();
            $('.bar').css('background-color','red');
            $('.error').text('Weak').show();
        }else

        //password moyen
        //1 type
        if((password.match(lettre_min)) && (password.match(nombre)) && password.length <12)
        {
            $('.bar').animate({width:'100px',height:'5px'},200).show();
            $('.bar').css('background-color','orange');
            $('.error').text('Average').show();
        }else ...
```

The problem is: if I put letters (lettre_min) AND numbers (nombre) on the form input, he tells me the password is weak when he should tell me that it is average. He totally ignores the second condition.

I have no clue what's going on =/

PS: I'm sorry if there is already an answer for this in an other question but I don't even know what the problem is, so I don't know what to search for =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Quick solution:

```
//password moyen
        //1 type
        if((password.match(lettre_min)) && (password.match(nombre)) && password.length <12)
        {
            $('.bar').animate({width:'100px',height:'5px'},200).show();
            $('.bar').css('background-color','orange');
            $('.error').text('Average').show();
        } else if((password.match(lettre_min)) && password.length <12)
        {
            $('.bar').animate({width:'75px',height:'5px'},200).show();
            $('.bar').css('background-color','red');
            $('.error').text('Weak').show();
        }
```

If `if((password.match(lettre_min)) && (password.match(nombre)) && password.length <12)` is true than `if((password.match(lettre_min)) && password.length <12)` is true too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tend to belive that the third condition doesn't gets evaluated because it's a bigger case of the second one, consider switching the second If with the third and it should work.

The second if can contain small letters but also numbers because the match() evaluates if it contains that sort of thing so before executing the second execute first the third one wich will also check if there are numbers, if there are not then check only for letters.

Answer (score 0):

Your order of the conditions to check the strength of the password is wrong. To fix it:

```
if((password.match(lettre_min)) && password.length <12){
   if(password.match(nombre)){
     //average
   }else{
     //weak
   }
}else if(password.length < 8){
   //too short
}else{
   //it must be strong
}
```